# JSON .NET Deserialize bad server response

Tags: c#, json

I need to deserialize a JSON respons from the [FastBill](https://www.fastbill.com/api/fastbill/en/fundamentals.html) API, (I'm using [JSON .NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)) I've created the C# class who will "hold" the data retrieved from the API response, the problem is that the response from the server is bad, looks like this:

`"{
    \"REQUEST\":{
        \"SERVICE\":\"invoice.get\",
        \"LIMIT\":1,
        \"FILTER\":{
            \"YEAR\":2018
        }
    },
    \"RESPONSE\":{
        \"INVOICES\":[{
            \"INVOICE_ID\":\"11586818\",
            \"TYPE\":\"outgoing\",
            \"CUSTOMER_ID\":\"4735248\",
            \"CUSTOMER_NUMBER\":\"3211\",
            \"CUSTOMER_COSTCENTER_ID\":\"0\",
            \"CONTACT_ID\":\"\",
            \"PROJECT_ID\":\"0\",
            \"CURRENCY_CODE\":\"EUR\",
            \"DELIVERY_DATE\":\"02.01.2018\",
            \"INVOICE_TITLE\":\"Rechnung f\\u00fcr Ihre Bestellung bei Amazon\",
            \"CASH_DISCOUNT_PERCENT\":\"0.00\",
            \"CASH_DISCOUNT_DAYS\":\"0\",
            \"SUB_TOTAL\":22.66,
            \"VAT_TOTAL\":4.31,
            \"VAT_ITEMS\":[{
                \"VAT_PERCENT\":\"19.00\",
                \"COMPLETE_NET\":22.66,
                \"VAT_VALUE\":4.3061344545
            }],
            \"ITEMS\":[{
                \"INVOICE_ITEM_ID\":\"33975736\",
                \"ARTICLE_NUMBER\":\"CK-7I70-IBD4\",
                \"DESCRIPTION\":\"Gr\\u00fcne Elefanten\\\\'s Bio OPC Traubenkernextrakt mit Bio Acerola Hochdosiert 2 Monatsvorrat - 390mg Kapseln Trauben aus Frankreich\",
                \"QUANTITY\":\"1.0000\",
                \"UNIT_PRICE\":\"22.66386555\",
                \"VAT_PERCENT\":\"19.00\",
                \"VAT_VALUE\":4.3061344545,
                \"COMPLETE_NET\":22.66386555,
                \"COMPLETE_GROSS\":26.9700000045,
                \"SORT_ORDER\":1
            }],
            \"TOTAL\":26.97,
            \"ORGANIZATION\":\"\",
            \"NOTE\":\"\",
            \"SALUTATION\":\"\",
            \"FIRST_NAME\":\"NAME\",
            \"LAST_NAME\":\"NAME\",
            \"ADDRESS\":\"ADDRESS\",
            \"ADDRESS_2\":\" \",
            \"ZIPCODE\":\"97493\",
            \"CITY\":\"CITY\",
            \"PAYMENT_TYPE\":\"1\",
            \"BANK_NAME\":\"\",
            \"BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER\":\"\",
            \"BANK_CODE\":\"\",
            \"BANK_ACCOUNT_OWNER\":\"\",
            \"BANK_IBAN\":\"\",
            \"BANK_BIC\":\"\",
            \"COUNTRY_CODE\":\"DE\",
            \"VAT_ID\":\"\",
            \"TEMPLATE_ID\":\"963360\",
            \"INVOICE_NUMBER\":\"3209\",
            \"INTROTEXT\":\"wir bedanken uns f\\u00fcr Ihre Bestellung bei Amazon (Bestellnummer 306-9638137-3397961). Der Zahlungsbetrag wurde bereits entrichtet.\",
            \"PAID_DATE\":\"2018-01-02 00:00:00\",
            \"IS_CANCELED\":\"0\",
            \"INVOICE_DATE\":\"2018-01-02\",
            \"DUE_DATE\":\"0000-00-00 00:00:00\",
            \"PAYMENT_INFO\":\"01\\\/02\\\/2018 26,
            97 \\u20ac () \",
            \"PAYMENTS\":[{
                \"PAYMENT_ID\":\"7640244\",
                \"DATE\":\"01\\\/02\\\/2018\",
                \"AMOUNT\":\"26.97\",
                \"CURRENCY_CODE\":\"EUR\",
                \"NOTE\":\"\",
                \"TYPE\":\"\"
            }],
            \"LASTUPDATE\":\"2018-01-02 17:29:21\",
            \"DOCUMENT_URL\":\"https:\\\/\\\/my.fastbill.com\\\/download\\\/DD0fDZvD1CUfB2S4TvLy8GgCuGNKqfbuiNLmn6pa895-yK0E6.20FV3zbC9EhWyC\"
        }]
    }
}"`

(The backslashes seems to appear only in the debugger, so isn't this the problem.)

If I left the response exactly as this, the runtime doesn't give any error, but the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` doesn't return the data from the response in the "fields" of the C# class, otherwise, if I remove the `REQUEST` and the `RESPONSE` header and leave only the `INVOICES` items, seems to "work", but now a new error appears from the compiler:

> 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'VAT_ITEMS', line 1, position 373.'

The C# class:

```
public class GET_INVOICE {
                public string INVOICE_ID             { get; set; }
                public string TYPE                   { get; set; }
                public string CUSTOMER_ID            { get; set; }
                public string CUSTOMER_NUMBER        { get; set; }
                public string CUSTOMER_COSTCENTER_ID { get; set; }
                public string CONTACT_ID             { get; set; }
                public string PROJECT_ID             { get; set; }
                public string CURRENCY_CODE          { get; set; }
                public string DELIVERY_DATE          { get; set; }
                public string INVOICE_TITLE          { get; set; }
                public string CASH_DISCOUNT_PERCENT  { get; set; }
                public string CASH_DISCOUNT_DAYS     { get; set; }
                public string SUB_TOTAL              { get; set; }
                public string VAT_TOTAL              { get; set; }
                public IList<string> VAT_ITEMS       { get; set; }
                public IList<string> ITEMS           { get; set; }
                public double TOTAL                  { get; set; }
                public string ORGANIZATION           { get; set; }
                public string NOTE                   { get; set; }
                public string SALUTATION             { get; set; }
                public string FIRST_NAME             { get; set; }
                public string LAST_NAME              { get; set; }
                public string ADDRESS                { get; set; }
                public string ADDRESS_2              { get; set; }
                public string ZIPCODE                { get; set; }
                public string CITY                   { get; set; }
                public string PAYMENT_TYPE           { get; set; }
                public string BANK_NAME              { get; set; }
                public string BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER    { get; set; }
                public string BANK_CODE              { get; set; }
                public string BANK_ACCOUNT_OWNER     { get; set; }
                public string BANK_IBAN              { get; set; }
                public string BANK_BIC               { get; set; }
                public string COUNTRY_CODE           { get; set; }
                public string VAT_ID                 { get; set; }
                public string TEMPLATE_ID            { get; set; }
                public string INVOICE_NUMBER         { get; set; }
                public string INTROTEXT              { get; set; }
                public string PAID_DATE              { get; set; }
                public string IS_CANCELED            { get; set; }
                public string INVOICE_DATE           { get; set; }
                public string DUE_DATE               { get; set; }
                public string PAYMENT_INFO           { get; set; }
                public IList<string> PAYMENTS        { get; set; }
                public string LASTUPDATE             { get; set; }
                public string DOCUMENT_URL           { get; set; }
            }
```

The deserialization

`JSON.GET_INVOICE GetInvoiceStruct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSON.GET_INVOICE>(_response);`

I really don't understand how I can successfully deserialize the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've successfully prepared model for main object you are deserializing.
Now you also need to model additional models for your collections:

- VAT_ITEMS
- ITEMS
- PAYMENTS

Currently you've modeled them as `string` but they are not strings at all, they are complex objects.
I'll provide you with example for `VatItem` and then you can complete the rest yourself.

Create `VatItem` model, ie:

```
public class VatItem 
{
    //Did not used decimal type because I don't know how JSON.NET handles it
    public double VAT_PERCENT { get; set; }
    public double COMPLETE_NET { get; set; }
    public double VAT_VALUE { get; set; }
}
```

to model this part of `json` response:

```
\"VAT_PERCENT\":\"19.00\",
\"COMPLETE_NET\":22.66,
\"VAT_VALUE\":4.3061344545
```

Then change in `GET_INVOICE` model your `VAT_ITEMS` collection to be:

```
public IList<VatItem> VAT_ITEMS { get; set; }
```

Follow the example with two additional collections to complete mapping.